# namespace "std" has no member "string_view"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std, string-view

I change my settings in Visual Studio *C++ language standard* to **Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest)**, but it still not letting me use `std::string_view` and shows me this message

> namespace "std" has no member "string_view"

Does somebody know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    std::string_view str{ "abc" };
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio version? Upgrade it to the newest.

Comment: Is this the only error message or do you also get an error that `string_view` include file is not found? Which VS version do you use? Which "C++ Language Standard" did you configure in the project settings?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.6.3 and yes this is the only message and yes the project settings

Comment: You should enable C++17 support in VS

Comment: i try enable c++17 also and it still not working

Comment: If you can't find C++17 in the project setting then you probably don't have the newest build tools installed https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: it show me that i have the latest build tool. MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.26)

Comment: When you select "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest)" in the project properties, make sure you're setting the properties for the Configuration and Platform that you're actually building.  When changing general properties like this one, I usually set the Configuration and Platform drop down lists at the top of the Project Properties dialog to "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".  Otherwise, you'd have to change it separately for Debug/Release and Win32/x64.

Comment: hello Adrian, thenk you! i am missing the All Platforms option this fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2019 (even community edition), you can right click on the project -> `Properties` -> `General` -> `C++ Language Standard` -> `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`
[image]

The image is from my Visual Studio 2022, but should be very similar on 2019 if my memory doesn't falter.